sap cpi xml script not running
In the Cloud Integration suite, when I made content modifer xml simple script it is not running:
Script:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Employee><EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID><Name>John</Name><LastName>Doe</LastName> <Pincode>123456</Pincode><Address>123 Main St</Address></Employee>

Error:

Message processing failed.
Processing Time: 16 ms
Error Details
org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed to invoke method: employeeData on null due to: org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with name: employeeData not found on bean: 


what should i do??
I want to in 1 content modifer have xml script  of data of employees, then second have dynamic header and property of last name, f n, address , pincode and third should have a msg containing hi i am insert name, address, pincode, etc as output.

hold on, are you sure this is not a [tag:java]? is it really related to power management on computer (the [tag:acpi] tag)?
